# ASP.Net (VB) - Downloading a file with Response.BinaryWrite isn't working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

Please note that I use the ASPxCallback control from DevExpress in the following code (doc: https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxCallback.class)

Here is my problem: I'm trying to allow user to download a file but it isn't working. I cannot use TransmitFile since it is from the database so I used BinaryWrite instead.
Here is my current implementation:

1) First, there is a Table that I populate from the code-behind like this:

```
For Each version As Fichier In fichiers.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.LastModifiedDate)
                Dim row As New TableRow()
                Dim cellFichier As New TableCell()
                Dim cellDate As New TableCell()
                Dim cellDownload As New TableCell()
                cellFichier.Text = idFile.ToString()
                cellDate.Text = version.LastModifiedDate.ToString()
                cellDownload.Text = String.Format("<img class='img-small' src='icons/DownloadFile_inverse_32x.png' onclick=""downloadRevisions({0});"" />", version.ID)
                row.Cells.Add(cellFichier)
                row.Cells.Add(cellDate)
                row.Cells.Add(cellDownload)
                tblFileVersions.Rows.Add(row)
                idFile = idFile + 1
            Next
```

2) The following javascript method is called:

```
function downloadRevisions(fileId) {
  callbackDownloadRevision.PerformCallback(fileId);
}
```

3) Finally, this callback method is called in code-behind:

```
 Protected Sub OpenEncryptedRevision(source As Object, e As CallbackEventArgs)
    Dim fileID As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(e.Parameter, fileID) Then
        Dim file As Fichier = Nothing
        Dim decryptedFileBytes As Byte() = DecryptRevision(fileID, file)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + file.FileName)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = True
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = GestionnaireFichiers.ContentType(file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal)))
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(decryptedFileBytes.ToArray())
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
    End If
End Sub
```

I debugged each function line by line and everything is going well. The file is correctly retrieved from the database and the header seems fine. I use the same method in another project and it works perfectly.
When the last method ends, nothing happens. I'm pretty sure that's a problem of callback but I really can't figure out where it can be.

I don't know if it can help but there is the html for the ASPxCallback:

```
<dx:ASPxCallback runat="server" ClientInstanceName="callbackDownloadRevision" ID="CallbackDownloadRevision" OnCallback="OpenEncryptedRevision" ></dx:ASPxCallback>
```

If I can provide any informations that helps just ask me !
Thank you in advance,
Evanzyker

Comment: Is any data sent back to the client? Does it work if you comment out the `HttpContext.Current.Response.End()` line?

Comment: Hi Andrew, it seems that no data is sent to the client. I tried to comment the line but it changed nothing.